# Anugular nested $http calls takes long time to execute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angular App. I have around 6 to 7  http chaining request and it takes long time to execute all the requests. How to optimize this?

```
empSvc.getallEmp().then(function (data) {
    if (data !== null && data.length > 0) {
        repos.saveEmp(data).then(function () {
            repos.getemp().then(function (result) {
                ctrl.emp= result;
                getsubordinates().then(function () {
                    deleteinactive(data).then(function () {
                        deleteinactiveSubordinate(ctrl.emp).then(function () {
                           console.log(success);

                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Please show us your code, if there isn't an inherent issue try the code review stackoverflow...

Comment: Please provide  a [mcve]. Perhaps some of them can be grouped into a `$q.all()`

Comment: @charlietfl- thanks , $q.all() helped me to reduce few secs.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with angular itself. If your http calls are slow, then they are slow because of your network connection speed, payload size and your backend server processing power.

If writing backend api functions and routes is up to you, then you can write a custom api route that combines all these 6-7 requests into one, and hands out all the necessary data at once.

e.g if you have something like this.
1) download product categories
2) download category products
3) download product details
4) download product comments
5) download product ratings.

You could write a single shortcut route that returns all this info in one result set.

```
e.g /products/{category}/all

and returns data:
{
  category: "Shoes",
  id: 2,
  related_categories: [1,3]
  products: [{
    id: 100,
    brand: "some random brand",
    color: "red",
    comments: ["awesome shoes"]
    ratings: [1,2,3]
  }]
}
```

combining the requests into one can give a significant speed boost and reduce overhead.

If your queries are not dependent on data from previous queries, then you may try executing them in parallel, all at once. Cant really help without any more info.

Quick update based on the update to your post.
Without knowing in more detail what those functions does, im just taking a guess here:

Looks like the angular app is trying to delete inactive users somewhere. 
Is it really something you need to be doing in the frontend in the first place ?

Im sure the backend server can handle deleting inactive users automatically using cron jobs.

you are downloading "data" to your frontend - only to send it back to server unchanged?
Seems so at least.

Give more details of what those functions do. where they submit their requests

Comment: my requirement is diff and i cant combine all the request data. Each and every request is dependent on another.

Comment: Anyways - whatever your issue is, it is not in angular, and not in your frontend. You can easily make 6 http requests in a second. The slowing down most likely is due to your network seed or server processing power being inadequate.